# Efficient way to move 170 GB table from production to another server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a 170 GB table that is no longer referenced.

I want to move that table to another server. I tried these options in staging:

- select into 8 GB table to another db - 1.47 min
- SSIS package - 6 min

Can anyone suggest best way to do it? How can I break table into parts so I can make small packages and upload it?

Comment: I would use the SSIS package as 6 minutes seems reasonable. Specify the fast load option along with a rows per batch (empty) and max insert commit size (100000).

Comment: @pravin gharvare , Is the table size you mentioned includes indexes also? Is scripting out the values and doing an import will acceptable for you?

Comment: @ Biju jose table don't  have any indexes, i have tried import export on 8 GB table on staging its taking 10 min time

Comment: @Dan Guzman i'm thinking to use this option. but can you tell me is there any option by which i can divide table into chunks and load data in batches.

Comment: The max commit size does exactly that. A commit is issued each time the specified limit is reached. This will keep the transaction log size reasonable. Additionally, specify the Table Lock option.

Comment: Do you not already have a backup somewhere where this table is in a reasonably current state? It's quite possible you have solutions here that don't involve touching the live production data.

Comment: What is the *real* constraint here? Disk space? Network pipe (you mention uploading data)? No backup? If the table is no longer in use then what is the issue with running a 6 minute SSIS job to migrate the data? I feel like we're missing some information.

Comment: Can't you take a snapshot from your database (while it is down), restart your database, copy the snapshot at your leisure to the other server and create a new database there?

Comment: I don’t see any explanation of what the problem is with the two approaches described in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

1) backup (copy-only) & restore the database on the same server to make this db available locally -> copy records into the other database. No option if the database itself is too large.

2) use bcp out/in. Use QueryOut if  you want to specify the records to be exported yourself (partition on PK value)

Comment: my db size is 450 GB

Answer (score 0):

As recommended on the other answer, I would suggest using a backup, maybe you already have a FULL backup from last night ready to be used (if not, I will suggest to immediately configure a job to run FULL backups at least on a weekly basis). You could run a backup with copy-only option that allows you to run a backup and don't break your backup chain.

```
BACKUP DATABASE your_database
TO DISK = '\\your_drive\BAK\your_database_copy_only_backup.bak'
WITH COPY_ONLY;
```

Once you have that BAK file, you can restore on your staging environment and do everything you need.

You commented that you database is 450GB, why that could be a problem? Don't you have enough space on the staging environment? If that is the case, then you will have a somewhat different approach. Maybe you could create a job that moves data from your prod server to the staging server and let it run in hours where your server has low traffic. If the server is not under heavy load, you could have 2 schedules, one that runs during the day, moving less amount of data and one at night moving more data.

And I guess once you have that table available on staging you will want to delete it from your PROD environment. Check [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/60800/9031) for some advice on how to delete it and recover the space, if needed. The code there refers to UPDATES, but for DELETE's is the same, here a sample to run a delete in chunks.

```
WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'

    DELETE TOP(10000)
    FROM [dbo].[myTable]
    WHERE []--condition here

    IF @@ROWCOUNT < 1 BREAK
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need table from Production for test purpose?

> - Back up your database `WITH COPY_ONLY, COMPRESSION` and .bak file copy to another server (must need enough space and better to copy .bak over share drives)
> - Restore DB to another server (restore with new name if needed)
> - Drop all of the tables you don't want.

```
BACKUP DATABASE db_name TO DISK = db_filename WITH COPY_ONLY, COMPRESSION
```

Backup the database and send that .bak over test environments.